# Filter dataframe for rows that match all elements in vector dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter for rows in a dataframe that have all elements in a vector in any combination of columns. For example, in the following situation:

```
test <- data.frame(x = c("foo", "ww12", "foo", "foo bar"),
           y = c("bar", "bar", "ww12", "www"),
           z = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

testString <- c("foo", "bar")
```

I want to filter for rows 1 and 4, since row 1 contains 'foo' in column x and 'bar' in column y, and row 4 contains 'foo bar' in column x.

I think I'm most of the way there with the following, but I can't quite get it to work:

```
test %>%
  filter(
    if_all(
      everything(),
      ~str_detect(., any(testString))
    )
  )
```

The test string may be any number of words long, or a single word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways you might go about this:

```
test[Reduce(`&`, lapply(testString, \(x) grepl(x, do.call(paste, test)))), ]

        x   y z
1     foo bar 1
2 foo bar www 4
```

You can avoid concatenating the rows with a nested loop:

```
test[Reduce(`&`, lapply(testString, \(x) Reduce(`|`, lapply(test, grepl, pattern = x)))), ]

        x   y z
1     foo bar 1
2 foo bar www 4
```

Or translated using tidyverse functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

test %>%
  filter(reduce(map(testString, \(x) if_any(everything(), str_detect, x)), `&`))

        x   y z
1     foo bar 1
2 foo bar www 4
```

To ignore case when matching, use:

```
test %>%
  filter(reduce(map(testString, \(x) if_any(everything(), str_detect, regex(x, ignore_case = TRUE))), `&`))

# Similarly

test[Reduce(`&`, lapply(testString, \(x) Reduce(`|`, lapply(test, grepl, pattern = x, ignore.case = TRUE)))), ]
```

Comment: I used the last one - very elegant. Thank you!

Comment: @anorlondo - no worries.  Note that the patterns will match words like "food" or "debar" - if you want an exact match you need to include boundaries in the regex.

Comment: That's fine - is it possible to amend the code to convert the columns to lowercase only while matching, so that it doesn't miss Foo or FOO, for example?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
test %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
  mutate(combined = paste(across(-z), collapse = " ")) %>%
  filter(all(map_lgl(testString, ~str_detect(combined, .x)))) %>%
  select(-combined)
```

It just creates a new column with all the values except z pasted together, and then checks that every value of `testString` is in this new column for every row

This also works:

```
test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(all(map_lgl(testString, ~ any(str_detect(c_across(-z), .)))))
```

Comment: I don't think that does it, as row 2 gets returned and row 4 does not.

Comment: oops, i misread it, updated!

Comment: The dataframe will have an arbitrary number of columns with arbitrary names, so that would need to be taken into account.

Comment: updated again! lmk what you think

Comment: Not to be a party pooper, but neither of those work either - row 4 has `"foo bar"` but doesn't have either `"foo"` or `"bar"` so won't match.

Comment: it's because "foo bar" is different to "foo", "bar". I didn't realise you were looking for a regex match!

Comment: okay now it should work